# Can't run Go binary after uploading to the server

Tags: go, cross-compiling, binaryfiles

I have a `Golang` project that Im using it to build a website using `Gin` framework and Go's internal https server. it works and everything is right. I create the final binary with this command:

```
go build -ldflags="-X 'main.DEBUG=FALSE'" main.go
```

Then I check it like this on my own machine:

```
./main
```

And everything is working like a charm. My machine information is(via uname -a):

I compile the app inside a Docker container(linux) on a Mac OSX

```
Linux defa27bc776c 5.10.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Mon Nov 8 10:21:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And if I check the file via `file ./main` command, I get this:

```
./main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=9a5dddf09839218486cc1955c1fdd7193e6c329c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

But my problem is when I upload it to a server. My server(it's a Docker container inside a cloud virtual machine) info via `uname -a` is:

```
Linux project-v2 5.4.0-72-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 17:35:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After uploading, when I check the file with `file ./main` command, I get this error:

```
main: ERROR: , statically linked, interpreter *empty* error reading (Invalid argument)
```

And if I want to run it, I get this error:

```
bash: ./main: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I tried to compile the app like this but it's the same and I get those errors:

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags="-X 'main.DEBUG=FALSE'" main.go
```

I also tried with `CGO_ENABLED=0` and I get these:

```
main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, too large section header offset 2106064896
```

And when I run it:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What I have to do? What's the problem here?

Comment: Have you verified the file was uploaded OK? Like, run `sha1sum` on the file after the compilation, and on the file after uploading. For instance, if you have used a FTP client for uploading which did not manage to enable "binary mode" before uploading, you will get botched file. Sure, there can be other reasons, but given the information provided, it's only possible to make sheer guesses.

Comment: What's the base image of the container you're using to build your binary ? Can you reproduce the problem with a minimum binary which just immediatly exits ? We do not have much information to help you.